# R remove month from a given incomplete date

Tags: r

I have a string like this: `year = "2011-01","2011-02","2011-03"`..... all the way to `"2015-012"`.

They represent `2011 Jan, 2011 Feb...` sth like that.

For simplicity, I will just say

`year1 <- c("2011-01","2011-02","2011-03")`

I was asked to return a four digit code(i.e. 2011,2012,2013)etc.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub`, which is a regular expression substituion function:

```
sub("-[0-9]+$", "", year1)
```

Comment: btw do you know how to remove year from a given date? i.e. I want 01, 02, 03 for example

Comment: `sub("[0-9]+-", "", year1)`

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `substr`

```
substr(year1, 1,4)
#[1] "2011" "2011" "2011"
```

Or we can use `as.yearmon` from `library(zoo)` to convert to a `yearmon` class and then extract the 'year' with `format`.

```
library(zoo)
format(as.yearmon(year1), '%Y')
#[1] "2011" "2011" "2011"
```

Comment: @LouisLee  If you need the month `substr(year1, 6,7)` or `format(as.yearmon(year1), '%m')`

Answer (score 1):

through split,

```
> unlist(lapply(strsplit(year1, "-"), function(x){ x[1]}))
[1] "2011" "2011" "2011"
```